# Multiple multi-line HAML blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Using the (intentionally) strange multi-line format for HAML, I'd like to have the following lines in my template:

```
= call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |

-# and

= call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |
```

However, they can not run up against one another, or they are read as one single multi-line block.

```
-# This fails:
= call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |
= call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |
```

And separating with a line break, interestingly enough, does no better:

```
-# This fails, too:
= call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |

= call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |
```

The only working solution I have found is to run a blank line of Ruby code between. Which looks really ugly.

```
= call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |
-
= call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |
```

Is there anything better?

Comment: **Update:** The pipes are not required in the latest version of HAML, so don't get hung up on this if you're just now stumbling across this question ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a feature, not a bug. Haml multiline blocks are intentionally unwieldy - including hard to follow one after another - because almost all the time it's better to put that Ruby code into a helper. Even if the helper is only called once, it will make your template much easier to read. For instance:

```
def blatz_link
  call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3',
    :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5'
end

def blootz_link
  call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3',
    :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5'
end
```

Then in your Haml, just do

```
= blatz_link
= blootz_link
```

which will be much more readable and easier to understand.

---

If you absolutely must follow one multiline block with another, just add a comment in between:

```
= call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |
-#
= call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |
```

Comment: I initially resisted, but eventually it just got so unwieldy with all the links (especially with, in the staff area, there being a "More" dropdown for managing a ton of other models), that I just gave up and restructured the code to be manageable. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

I've encountered the same problems and workarounds as have been mentioned here, and the weird (and yes, it IS weird) behavior of HAML with regard to multi-line blocks has bitten me quite a few times. I know that it's intentional and that it was probably intended to force the user to make his code easier to read. However, it's a well known fact that every developer has his own preferences when it comes to structuring code. HAML is the only language I know of (c, c++, ruby, python, HTML, etc.) that tries to impose such restrictions.

Calling the weird multi-line handling a feature rather than a bug, just indicates a flawed language design. In the end it will always be a bug in the eyes of the user. Multi-line support is a basic feature of any main stream language and the lack of this feature is just plain annoing - just like the M$ paperclip, which I believe was also an attempt to guide the user.

That being said, HAML is a fantastically compact and useful language for writing HTML. Those of us who (in some cases) prefer multi-line blocks would just love to at least be offered some kind of configuration option to enable/disable decent multi line block support - regardless of the language designer's personal definition of "easy to read code".

Until we get there, I guess we'll have to work around the language using the "-#" hack...

Comment: Don't these sorts of restrictions create a better ecosystem though? It encourages new and old users alike to follow similar styles and patterns, which enables greater sharing and allows people to onboard onto projects faster. "Personal styles" are by their very nature not scalable. It's fine if you never want your project to see the light of day of have contributors, that's fine, but this makes the default habits more collaborative.

Comment: If the HAML style is actually beneficial sure. I think your code ends up easier to maintain if you can keep your logic in the template, the one place it is used, instead of having to create a one-off method in a utility module. Anywhere else in your code I think that would be Premature Abstraction with all the usual problems. I'm not sure why it's a good thing in your templates. Conventions reduce knowledge transfer but that doesn't mean they can't be a bad idea and end up costing everyone more time in the end.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a block on your helper, yielding whatever makes sense.

```
module SomeHelper
  def call_to_helper
    foo = Foo.new
    yield foo
    # build your html here, using the foo object's attributes
  end

  class Foo
    attr_accessor :foo1, :foo2, :foo3, :foo4, :foo5
  end

end
```

Now on your haml:

```
= call_to_helper do |foo|
  -foo.foo1 = 'bar1'
  -foo.foo2 = 'bar2'
  -foo.foo3 = 'bar3'
  -foo.foo4 = 'bar4'
  -foo.foo5 = 'bar5'

= call_to_helper do |foo|
  -foo.foo1 = 'bar1'
  -foo.foo2 = 'bar2'
  -foo.foo3 = 'bar3'
  -foo.foo4 = 'bar4'
  -foo.foo5 = 'bar5'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack (sort-of), but you could always use a "+" instead of a "=" on your 2nd, 3rd, etc. lines in the chain.

```
= call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |
+ call_to_helper :foo1 => 'bar1', :foo2 => 'bar2', :foo3 => 'bar3', |
  :foo4 => 'bar4', :foo5 => 'bar5' |
```

Comment: Haha, clever. It's definitely nicer than some random dash stuck in the middle :P

Comment: In my case the problem blocks were not `=` but `%`, so this doesn't work for me.