# Multiline strings in HAML template helpers

Tags: ruby, haml

I'd like to be able to pass a multiline string to a haml helper.

I have a function format_code, that accepts a string and a set of line numbers to highlight.

The purpose of this function is to convert raw source into formatted HTML with highlighted lines, line numbers, newlines converted to brs, etc.

If I call it like this:

```
%p Some HAMl

=format_code("def something
  a = b
  b = c
end", :highlight_line => 2)

%p Some more HAML
```

The reason for doing this is to embed a code example into a HAML document.

HAML complains about nesting in plain text. The nesting takes place within a string so I had assumed this would be OK. The same call works fine in irb.

I would use a helper, but I want to be able to pass a parameter hash. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm supposing you want to hardcode a code example into a HAML template, so you really want something to which my immediate response is: "you don't want this". In that case, I would probably choose:

```
:ruby
  code = <<-CODE
    def something
      a = b
      b = c
    end
  CODE

%p Some HAMl

=format_code(code, :highlight_line => 2)

%p Some more HAML
```

Comment: is there a way to make a `:ruby` block that outputs to haml?

Answer (score 0):

I tried different variants, and I think the easiest one is the following (code taken directly from yours):

```
%p Some HAMl

=format_code("def something\t  a = b\t  b = c\tend", :highlight_line => 2)

%p Some more HAML
```

This should at least the problem with multiple lines ...

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that I have to reformat my code onto a single line. I'm creating content so it needs to remain legible to me.

Comment: So perhaps using the technique in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1475274/41540 could give you another working solution. You move the ruby code to a helper file, where HAML does not hinder you.

Comment: This would work, but in this instance, since the code is part of the content, I'd prefer to keep the source more legible. I'm creating a document which includes formatted code samples, so I don't want to extract parts of said content into other files. Confusion has a good solution in which the code blocks are defined as strings within the ruby filter, then parsed within HAML.